# FINDSTR cannot open path with spaces

Tags: path, batch-file, space, findstr

Drag and drop .bat, it takes the files,
puts it in 2 lists and process both list simultanously.

I passed a path : `X:\folder\folder number\begin.txt` into `%1`
it's working fine if i have `foldernumber`

```
PUSHD %~dp0
:loop
    IF ["%~f1"] EQU [""] goto :out

    echo %~f1>>list
    set /a count+=1
    SHIFT
goto :loop

POPD
:out

if %count% LEQ 1 (copy list list1 && goto :START)
set /a count2=%count%/2
more /e +%count2% list > list2

set count=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "eol=; tokens=* delims=," %%i in (list) do (
    set /a count+=1
    if !count! leq !count2! echo %%i >>list1    
)
endlocal

:: Create the 2nd .bat for multiprocessing and start multiprocessing
more /e +88 mybat.bat > temp.bat
START "2nd Process mybat2" temp.bat

:start
    for /f "eol=; tokens=* delims==," %%i in (list1) do call :SEARCH %%i
    goto :END
:: 88th line here
    for /f "eol=; tokens=* delims==," %%k in (list2) do call :SEARCH %%k
    goto :END

:search
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%A in (jan feb mar apr mai etc...) DO (
        findstr /m "%%A" "%~f1" > NUL
        if !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 (
            call :theend %~1 %%A
            goto :EOF
        )
    )
    endlocal
```

I get this error message **"FINDSTR: Cannot open X:\folder\folder number\begin.txt"**
Is there a way to fix this findstr problem?
thanks

Comment: are you sure the error message is not "FINDSTR: Cannot open X:\folder\folder" ? this would inequivocaly mean you missed to pass the filename around quotes as @jeb was mentioning

Comment: mybatch takes drag&drop files, it works fine if there are _no spaces in the folder name._

Comment: and what is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

To let us see if your file dropping is OK:

Can you create a batch file with these contents

```
echo %*
set /p dummy=press return
```

drop a file, with spaces in the name, onto it and post the results?

Comment: "X:\folder\folder number\begin.txt"

Comment: There you go... quotes are required for cmd prompt if spaces are involved in file paths.